# How to extend client side widget to load additional components in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to extend a client side widget (Alfresco.eventInfo) to add additional components to the widget to be loaded, namely datasource, datatable, json.
This is essentially achieved by the following line :

```
Alfresco.util.YUILoaderHelper.require(["button", "container", "connection"], this.onComponentsLoaded, this);
```

for each widget instance.
How can I extend the widget to load the addition modules needed?

Comment: can please tell me what kind of things you want to extend in datasource or any other widgets?